# Why my Single Linked List implementation is giving me my first element twice after adding objects?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here i am trying to implement the basic operations of "**Single Linked List**".
But only here i am facing only one problem that is, after adding elements, i.e.

```
al.add("Ravi");
al.add("Vijay");
al.add("Sanjay");
al.add("Ajay");
```

I am getting output as:
[]--------->For empty Linked list
[**Ravi,Ravi**,Vijay,Sanjay,Ajay]------>After adding elements.

```
class MyLinkedList {
        private Node first;
        private Node last;
        private int count;

        public void add(Object ele){
            if(first==null){
                first=new Node(ele);
                last=first;
                count++;
            }
            last.next=new Node(ele);
            last=last.next;
            count++;
        }
        public int size(){
            return count;
        }
        public Object get(int index){
            if(index>=size())throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            Node p=first;
            for(int i=0;i<=index;i++){
                p=p.next;
            }
            return p.ele;
        }
        public void remove(int index){
            if(index>=size())throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            if(index==0){
                first=first.next;
                count--;
                return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            if(size()==0)return "[]";
            Node p=first;
            String s="[" + p.ele;
            while(p.next!=null){
                p=p.next;
                s+=","+p.ele;
            }
            return s + "]";
        }

        private class Node{
            Object ele;
            Node next;
            Node(Object ele){
                this.ele=ele;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
             MyLinkedList al=new MyLinkedList(); 
             System.out.println(al);
              al.add("Ravi");  
              al.add("Vijay");  
              al.add("Sanjay");  
              al.add("Ajay");
              System.out.println(al);

        }

    }
```

Comment: So what is your problem, exactly? What output are you expecting? What have you tried to fix this issue? Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Yes,I have checked.Expected output should be:[Ravi,Vijay,Sanjay,Ajay]        instead of :[Ravi,Ravi,Vijay,Sanjay,Ajay]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you add it twice:

```
    public void **add**(Object ele){
        if(first==null){
            first=new Node(ele); //First
            last=first;
            count++;
        }
        last.next=new Node(ele); //second.
        last=last.next;
        count++;
    }
```

add an else Statement:

```
    public void **add**(Object ele){
        if(first==null){
            first=new Node(ele);
            last=first;
            count++;
        } else {
          last.next=new Node(ele);
          last=last.next;
          count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,I thought the problem is in toString() method implementation.But, because of **else** i am not getting the desired output.Thanks Buddy!!!

Answer (score 2):

In your method:

```
 public void **add**(Object ele){
    if(first==null){
       first=new Node(ele);
       last=first;
       count++;
    }
    last.next=new Node(ele);
    last=last.next;
    count++;
 }
```

You have to put a `return` statement at the end of the if clause, or use `else`. Else you add the first element twice.

Comment: @GAJENDRATIWARI you can't accept two answers, but you can upvote both

Answer (score 0):

In this method

```
public void add(Object ele){
        if(first==null){
            first=new Node(ele);
            last=first;
            count++;
        }
        last.next=new Node(ele);
        last=last.next;
        count++;
    }
```

You have to **return** from the if statement as shown below, otherwise the first value will be inserted twice as the control will be transferred to the next statement after the execution of if block. You can also put the remaining code under the **else** block, it will also work.

```
public void add(Object ele){
        if(first==null){
            first=new Node(ele);
            last=first;
            count++;
            return; 
        }
        last.next=new Node(ele);
        last=last.next;
        count++;
    }
```